# Creating a game in Pygame encountered an IndentationError error

Tags: python

I ran into an indentation problem, but I rechecked my code and couldn't find the error, please help

Game:

```
import pygame, controls
from gun import Gun
from pygame.sprite import Group
from stats import Stats

def run():

  pygame.init()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 600))
  pygame.display.set_caption('Game1')
  bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
  gun = Gun(screen)
  bullets = Group()
  inos = Group()
  controls.create_army(screen, inos)
  stats = Stats()

  while True:
    controls.events(screen, gun, bullets)
    gun.update_gun()
    controls.update(bg_color, screen, gun, inos, bullets)
    controls.update_bullets(inos, bullets)
    controls.update_inos(stats, screen, gun, inos, bullets)
run()
```

Gun:

```
import pygame

class Gun():

  def __init__(self, screen):

    self.screen = screen
    self.image = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ralph\Downloads\Python\Game\Image\t2.png")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    self.mright = False
    self.mleft = False


  def output(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

  def update_gun(self):
    if self.mright and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
      self.center += 1.5
    if self.mleft and self.rect.left > 0:
      self.center -= 1.5

    self.rect.centerx = self.center

  def create_gun(self):
    self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

Bullet:

```
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  def __init__(self, screen, gun):
    super(Bullet, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 3, 12)
    self.color = 150, 150, 150
    self.speed = 1.5
    self.rect.centerx = gun.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = gun.rect.top
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

  def update(self):
    self.y -= self.speed
    self.rect.y = self.y 

  def draw_bullet(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Control:

```
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
from ino import Ino
import time

def events(screen, gun, bullets):
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        gun.mright = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        gun.mleft = True
      elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet = Bullet(screen, gun)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        gun.mright = False
      elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        gun.mleft = False

def update(bg_color, screen, gun, inos, bullets):
  screen.fill(bg_color)
  for bullet in bullets.sprites():
    bullet.draw_bullet()
  gun.output()
  inos.draw(screen)
  pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(inos, bullets):
  bullets.update()
  for bullet in bullets.copy():
    if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
      bullets.remove(bullet) 
  collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, inos, True, True)

def gun_kill(stats, screen, gun, inos, bullets):
  stats.guns_left -= 1
  inos.empty()
  bullets.empty()
  create_army(screen, inos)
  gun.create_gun()
  time.sleep(2)

def update_inos(stats, screen, gun, inos, bullets):
  inos.update()
  if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(gun, inos):
    gun_kill(stats, screen, gun, inos, bullets)

def create_army(screen, inos):
  ino = Ino(screen)
  ino_width = ino.rect.width
  number_ino_x = int((700 - 2 * ino_width) / ino_width)
  ino_height = ino.rect.height
  number_ino_y = int((800 - 300 - 2 * ino_height) / ino_height)

  for row_number in range(number_ino_y):
    for ino_number in range(number_ino_x):
      ino = Ino(screen)
      ino.x = ino_width + (ino_width * ino_number)
      ino.y = ino_height + (ino_height * row_number)
      ino.rect.x = ino.x
      ino.rect.y = ino.rect.height + (ino.rect.height * row_number)
      inos.add(ino)
```

Army:

```
import pygame 

class Ino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  def __init__(self, screen):
    super(Ino, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ralph\Downloads\Python\Game\Image\solder.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = self.rect.width
    self.rect.y = self.rect.height
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

  def draw(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

  def update(self):
    self.y += 0.05
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

Stat

```
class Stats():

  def __init__(self):



  def reset_stats(self):
    self.guns_left = 2
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ralph\Downloads\Python\Game\game1.py", line 4, in
> from stats import Stats
> File "C:\Users\ralph\Downloads\Python\Game\stats.py", line 7
> def reset_stats(self):
> ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 3

I couldn't find the cause of the error but I believe the whole code is correct

Comment: An indentation error has nothing to do with pygame. It is a python syntax error. [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Comment: Your __init__ function's body is empty; here is the error; fill it with `pass` as a placeholder (read the error message carefully! . "...expected an indented block after function definition on line 3"

Comment: Instead of passing, the `__init__()` function should probably call `self.reset_stats()`